# How to clear dependent drop down list when value in parent cell is changed

Tags: excel, vba

I have dependent dropdown in column "H" (row 8-44). Cells of column "I" is dependent on cells of column "H" and that of "J" is dependent on "I".
I want to clear the values in cells of column "I" and "J" whenever I change the drop down selection in cells of column "H". I want to do this to all the cells of column "H" from row 8-34.
Can anyone help me with the VBA code. I am new to VBA and don't have much idea around it.

Thanks

Comment: You can research the `Worksheet_Change` event.

Comment: "I have dependent dropdown" - exactly how does that work?

Comment: I have used data validation and an offset function in the Source bar of data validation.